# Warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, vector

Declaration of code:

```
$char Primeiro[5][20] = {"Pedro", "Tiago", "Ana", "Bruno", "Camila"};
$char Meio[5][20] = {"Oliveira", "Antunes", "Ferreira", "Santos", "Cunha"};
$char Sobrenome[5][20] = {"Cardoso", "Silva", "Azevedo", "Monteiro", "Soares"};
$char *vNomeCompleto[125][60];
$ vNomeCompleto[i][i] = strcat(Primeiro[iPrimeiro], strcat(Meio[iSegundo], Sobrenome[iTerceiro]));
```

I can not make the vector `vNomeCompleto` receive the other three vectors.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do in this statement? vNomeCompleto[i][i] = strcat(Primeiro[iPrimeiro], strcat(Meio[iSegundo], Sobrenome[iTerceiro])); the statement looks ok, looks like you trying to concatenate all strings. is this the statement that caused error?

Comment: You have defined a 3D arrary. the statement is valid. but did you allocate memory for vNomeCompleto? Do you really need a 3D array there?

Comment: The warning indicates assigning a pointer to an integer data type. For example,  int i; char *p.   i = p;

Comment: What is the significance of the `$` symbols?  One context that I know of where they have meaning is in (Informix) ESQL/C, but that's rather specialized.  What would be the difference if the `$` symbols were removed?

Comment: the statement is not ok, since strcat does not return the concatenated string, it returns a destination. What strcat does is this: Appends a copy of the second string to the first string.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot `#include <string.h>`.  Apart from that there is no instance of assigning integer to pointer in your code.  Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Z0133 actually `strcat` does return the start of the concatenated string

Comment: thanks Umamahesh P, about symbol $ I tried to comment code, I'll try your recomendation.

Comment: Umamahesh P, i tried allocate memory of they following example;

Comment: for (i = 0; i < 125; i++) {
                                //vNomeCompleto[0][0] = (char**) malloc(125* sizeof(char*));
                                //vNomeCompleto[0][0] = (char*) malloc(3* sizeof(char));
                                //vNomeCompleto[0][0] = strcat(Primeiro[iPrimeiro], strcat(Meio[iSegundo], Sobrenome[iTerceiro]));
                                *vNomeCompleto[i] = Primeiro[iPrimeiro],Meio[iSegundo], Sobrenome[iTerceiro];
                            }

Answer (score 1):

1. vNomeCompleto declared as array of char* pointers - no memory for strings are allocated, just pointers.
2. strcat(Meio[iSegundo], Sobrenome[iTerceiro]) - you trying to add 20 more characters to Meio[i] which is has 20 max len - expect "out of bound" error in some cases. The same for first strcat.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char Primeiro[5][20] = { "Pedro", "Tiago", "Ana", "Bruno", "Camila" };
    char Meio[5][20] = { "Oliveira", "Antunes", "Ferreira", "Santos", "Cunha" };
    char Sobrenome[5][20] = { "Cardoso", "Silva", "Azevedo", "Monteiro", "Soares" };
    char vNomeCompleto[5][400];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        strcpy(vNomeCompleto[i], Primeiro[i]);
        strcat(vNomeCompleto[i], Meio[i]);
        strcat(vNomeCompleto[i], Sobrenome[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the `vNomeCompleto` contains:

```
PedroOliveiraCardoso
TiagoAntunesSilva
AnaFerreiraAzevedo
BrunoSantosMonteiro
CamilaCunhaSoares
```